# Localizable resource content in which images are set within the sentance

Tags: wpf, silverlight, localization, globalization, resx

This is a WPF/SL app, but this would apply elsewhere.

I have a contextually sensitive help message that directs the user if they run into a situation of no content.  In the middle I want to place an icon that corresponds to a toolbar button that could also be used.  I'm trying to create image recognition with the user to the action and the icon.

Here's what it looks like:

> Click New button [icon here] to begin creating your first thing in this area.

Unfortunately the order of works in different langauges wouldn't put the icon between 'button' and 'to'.  How have others solved this situation?

[UPDATE] To further explain the problem, many languages do not translate such that 'Click New Button' would come before 'to begin creating your first...'.  Instead the words are mixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you localize the entire string (including the resource path) for each language in an order that makes sense?  Or maybe have the icon always in the same place (i.e. at the beginning of the sentence or at the end)?

Like, if you're localizing for Yoda-speak, can you localize the entire sentence to:

```
[image] Here you will click for the creation of your first thing.
```

I don't know how your resources are set up, but you should be able to include the full Uri in the resx.

Comment: That's what we do now, but we wanted to get it close to the noun 'new button'.  It's a bit arbitrary to see the icon at the beginnin of the sentance.

Answer (score 2):

Radical idea - Don't put the image in the context-sensitive help at all - create an animation that draws a moving arrow from your context-sensitive help directly to the control in question.  Make it generic so you can pass the two control IDs between which the arrow should move, and then have the animation repeat until the user clicks the button or otherwise clicks away from the help screen.

Other options include making the button/UI element in question glow subtly to draw attention to it - slightly less direct but would also probably work.

Implementation is left as an exercise for the poster.

Comment: Love it!  Think we are going to go with a subtle glow behind that button when this scenario comes up.

Answer (score 0):

If the entire string, including the reference to the image, is handed off for localization, then any qualified translator will be able to position the image in the appropriate place in the sentence. For instance, if I received this sentence to translate:

Click New button [icon here] to begin creating your first thing in this area.

in German I would write:

Klicken Sie auf die Schaltflaeche 'Neu' [icon here], um das erste Element zu erstellen.

whereby [icon here] is the reference to the image. Any qualified translator will know where to place the image reference so it makes sense in the respective target language context.

On the other hand, if you're concatenating the string at runtime from two different sentence fragments whereby the word order Subject - Object - Infinitive Phrase is hard-coded, translators will complain because word order is dependent on the syntax of the target language. If you're going to be doing this a lot, researching general internationalization and localization issues would be advisable because people have been dealing with these things for over 20 years now and many issues already have well-defined answers. Good luck.